# Sum of functions in R

Tags: r

I have a function in R and I wish to take the sum of this function with different values. However, since I have a break condition (made by an `if` statement) I cannot just do this explicitly:

```
F<- function(x) if(x<5) 1 else 0
sum(F(seq(1,10,1))
#[1] 1
#Warning message:
#In if (x < 5) 1 else 0 :
#  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

so it is trying to do the sequence *of the function* and not the *sum of the sequence*. I wish to avoid the `for` loop as this can make long codes very cluttered; specifically to avoid ugly nested `for` loops.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Perhaps, you could try `F <- function(x) ifelse(x <5, 1, 0)` or if you just want the `sum` even `F1 <- function(x) x < 5`

Comment: @akrun Why does `ifelse(test,yes,no)` treat the sequence of the sum as expected while `if(cond) cons.expr else alt.expr` does not?
The example in the question perhaps does not reflect that I wish to be able to replace 1 and 0 in the `if` statement with more complex values (or functions).

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorised while`if` expects a single element or length of 1.  Because you didn't show what you wish to do, it is difficult to comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like to avoid for-loops, sapply is an option for you, because it is faster.

```
sapply(seq(1,10,1), FUN <- function(x) {if(x<5) 1 else 0})
```

Comment: I really like this answer because it intuitively makes sense to me: _Apply this to that_.

Comment: Before making such a claim, please run a time test.  It's rarely the case that `*apply` is faster than an explicit `for` loop; these functions are primarily for ease and conciseness of code.

Comment: oh, okay. I was just citing what they told us in university. I haven't done any time tests myself. where do you know from, that *apply isn't faster than for-loops? (we're all here to learn :-) )

Comment: @KKrenz skim thru old posts to SO, or read some of the online tutorials.  I don't know who "they" is, so can't comment on whether it's a computerphobic old professor or an undereducated grad student who's handing out bad info :-(  .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks for giving me directions where to look it up ;-) Don't worry about my lecturers

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Vectorize`:

```
F_v <- Vectorize(F)
sum(F_v(seq(1,10,1)))
# [1] 4
```